# texture painting on an imported DXF file

Tags: texture-painting

I have imported a dxf file of a roadway. I used the merge selected (ctrl m) to merge the individual polys. I converted to mesh as well. I unwrapped the UVs and tried to paint the model in Texture Paint. I am unable to paint on the object. I started a new project and unwrapped a cube and followed the procedure for texture painting and was successful. Does it have something to do with the DXF imported file?

I am using Blender 3.3 with K-Cycles

Comment: Can you check the face normals in edit mode to confirm they are pointing the correct direction, and that you have an image texture loaded in the object material?

Comment: forgive me but I do not know how to mark this answer as accepted. Help

Comment: You can't mark comments as accepted. If @CraigDJones comment gave you the correct answer I'd suggest you ask him to write it up as an answer and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Craig D Jones.... This answer did the trick